# Laravel cannot use mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I get a error when trying to use mysql_fetch_array() within Laravel.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

What to use instead mysql_fetch_array()?

Error I got,

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given

full part,

```
//prepare the tag cloud array for display
    $terms = array(); // create empty array
    $maximum = 0; // $maximum is the highest counter for a search term

    $query = DB::select('SELECT term, counter FROM search ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 30');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $term = $row['term'];
        $counter = $row['counter'];

        // update $maximum if this term is more popular than the previous terms
        if ($counter > $maximum) $maximum = $counter;

        $terms[] = array('term' => $term, 'counter' => $counter);

    }
```

Comment: Add the full thing

Comment: Why? Why would you do this??? Just use the `DB` functions instead

Comment: How to use DB function in here? DB::??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DB` statements and selects return the results, not a query object, so you just need to iterate through the results.

```
$results = DB::select('SELECT term, counter FROM search ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 30');

foreach($results as $row)
{
    $term = $row->term;
    $counter = $row->counter;

    // update $maximum if this term is more popular than the previous terms
    if ($counter > $maximum) $maximum = $counter;

    $terms[] = array('term' => $term, 'counter' => $counter);

}
```

More information on running raw queries through the DB class can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#running-queries).

Comment: Now it's generates an error as, FatalErrorException in AdminViewController.php line 84:
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. Line 84 is "$term = $row['term'];"

Comment: Ah, I can never remember if it's an object or array, and I think it's changed between 4 and 5. I'll update my answer with it as an object.

Comment: Yea now it's working! I'm new to laravel. That's why I didn't notice them. Thanks! :)

Comment: Oh I tried before but they told me to wait for 6 minutes. Done!

Comment: wont this return all results into var `DB::select`?

Answer (score -1):

Since you have used an associative array to extract data from the database you can also specify a flag in mysql_fetch_array() which is MYSQL_ASSOC.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "peter", "abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("test_db",$con);
$sql = "SELECT * from Person WHERE Lastname='Refsnes'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

For more details try:http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/php/func_mysql_fetch_array.asp.htm

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.